# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'successful_authenticator'

Tags: django, authentication, token, django-rest-framework

I've made an authentication class just like that :

[Token Authentication for RESTful API: should the token be periodically changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567586/token-authentication-for-restful-api-should-the-token-be-periodically-changed)

`restapi/settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'restapi.authentication.ExpiringTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10
}
```

`restapi/authentication.py`

```
import datetime
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

class ExpiringTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
        try:
            token = self.model.objects.get(key=key)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid token')

        if not token.user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User inactive or deleted')

        # This is required for the time comparison
        utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
        utc_now = utc_now.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

        if token.created < utc_now - timedelta(hours=24):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Token has expired')

        return token.user, token
```

`restapi/tests.py`

```
def test_get_missions(self):
    """
    Tests that /missions/ returns with no error
    """
    response = self.client.get('/missions/', HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = self.auth)
```

In my tests, I have an exception `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'successful_authenticator'`

Why am I having this error? How to fix it?

Comment: should `self.request` not be `request.` ?

Comment: what do you mean it is not related?

Comment: 1. I removed `self.` but it did not change anything 2. Looking at the code, at some point `self.request` is set with `request`.

Comment: You probably need to add more information to the question.  What type of view are you using, what does your authentication class look like, how are you setting the auth class on the view (by the `REST_FRAMEWORK` setting or `authentication_classes` on the view) etc...

Comment: do a `dir(self.request)` may be you might not be calling `self.request.successful_authenticator` the right way.

Comment: I have edited the question with additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes from the line:

```
utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
```

which causes `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'successful_authenticator'`.

It's been a while since I've stumbled upon such a misleading error message.

Here is how I solved it:

`restapi/authentication.py`

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class ExpiringTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
        try:
            token = self.model.objects.get(key=key)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid token')

        if not token.user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User inactive or deleted')

        utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)

        if token.created < utc_now - datetime.timedelta(hours=24):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Token has expired')

        return (token.user, token)
```

Comment: I had a similar problem caused trying to access `user.username` on a custom user model

Comment: I just encountered this kind of issue as well, that is, a general exception in authentication. It looks like the exception gets masked as a successful authentication but without request.user and auth objects set.

Comment: Guys, similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427180/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-auth) can you help?

Comment: Then similar solution, have you tried changing your naive datetime object?

Answer (score 5):

For me this had nothing to do with the custom authentication classes but with how the method calls defined in my `dispatch()` function were handled. For example, I had the following setup:

```
class MyView(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'my_field'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The `self.get_object` function calls two things I was interested in. Mainly the `self.check_object_permissions` function and the `get_object_or_404` function. For me it went wrong in the `check_object_permissions` function if it would return `False`. This would result in a call to `self.permission_denied()` which would then try to access the `successful_authenticator` attribute on the request. But because the request is not set to a `rest_framework.request.Request` the attribute would not exist. This is because the `dispatch` method sets this correct request during it's progression. Since this is done *after* the `self.get_object()` call it never gets set correctly.

Personally this quite surprised me since the `dispatch()` function is usually used to determine if certain critical things are true or not (i.e. if the object exists and if the user has permission). If that's all fine we continue with handling the request. But apparently there's no way to do this with this view. The only way I could resolve it was to move the `self.get_object()` call to my `get()` method like so:

```
class MyView(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'my_field'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_object = self.get_object()
```

I also tried moving around manual calls to `self.check_object_permissions` and `get_object_or_404` in the `dispatch()` function, but to no avail. One requires the other (permission check needs to object, and to get the object you have to do the 404 check). And trying to call the super before the permission and 404 check means that the `get()` function will get called first, basically negating the effect you were trying to get in the `dispatch` function in the first place. So as far as I can tell this is the only way to resolve it in this case.

Also see this issue on django-rest-framework for some interesting information: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/918