# Django Rest Framework Custom authentication + Basic Auth

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, custom-authentication

I am using the Django Rest Framework in my Python-Django app, and am using a Custom authentication for the api.

If I work just with my custom authentication method, works correctly.

```
 @authentication_classes((CustomAuthentication,  ))
```

But If I try to have basic authentication and my custom authentication, in that order, my custom authentication never executes. I mean, I want that if the Basic authentication fails, then try with the custom authentication. The Basic Authentication is executes and then ends.

```
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, CustomAuthentication ))
```

Is possible to have at the same time this three authentication methods, and execute them in that order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arpit Goyal's answer makes the workflow clear.

If you INDEED want to go through all the authentication classes,

here's a **work around** solution you can try. I hope it can help you.

```
@authentication_classes((AuthencationWrapper,  ))
```

add a `AuthencationWrapper`

```
class AuthencationWrapper(BaseAuthentication):

    authenication_classes = (
        BasicAuthentication,
        SessionAuthentication,
        CustomAuthentication,
    )

    def authenticate(self, request):
        exc = None
        ret = None
        for auth in self.authentication_classes:
            try:
                ret = auth().authenticate(request)
                # if success, we will break, else we will continue to call next one
                break
            except exceptions.AuthenticationFailed as e:
                # we only record the first failed exception
                if exc is None:
                    exc = e
                    self.first_failed_auth = auth()
        if ret is None:
            raise exc

        # one of the authentication_classes is passed
        return ret

    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        # actualy this way breaks what django-rest-framework doing now
        return self.first_failed_auth.authenticate_header(request)

        # the one follows what django-rest-framework doing now
        # choose the first authentication class header
        ## if self.authentication_classes:
        ##      return self.authentication_classes[0].authenticate_header(request)
```

Comment: Having that error `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'successful_authenticator `. 
Find that issue, but seems to not be the same: [stacklink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736710/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-successful-authenticator)

Comment: if your `CustomAuthentication` fails, do you raise an `exceptions.AuthenticationFailed` error?

Comment: try just with 
`authenication_classes = (
        BasicAuthentication,
        SessionAuthentication
    )`
And having the same error.

Comment: Solved, seems that `ret = auth().authenticate(request)`was not instantiating correctly the class, have to do in another line.

Answer (score 0):

The `Django Rest Framework` authentication [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined) clearly states this:

> The authentication schemes are always defined as a list of classes.
>   REST framework will attempt to authenticate with each class in the
>   list, and will set request.user and request.auth using the return
>   value of the first class that successfully authenticates.
>
> If no class authenticates, request.user will be set to an instance of
>   django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser, and request.auth will be set
>   to None.

So whenever your first class authenticates `request.user` and `request.auth` is set.

In case you want to authenticate with your `CustomAuthentication` class `return None` for `BasicAuthentication` so that all your authentication classes are used but the user is set as per your `CustomAuthentication`

Comment: if the first authentication class failed, it will raise an Exception, so the second authentication class will never be reached.

Comment: considering the input of @soooooot here is the documentation which states django rest framework's authentication in case of unauthorized or forbidden responses.