# how long is token valid? Django REST Framework

Tags: django, rest, token, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework token-authentication mechanism.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication

It creates database table with field `created` with the value equal to the timestamp, when te token was created. E.g: `2014-04-07 07:42:50.395626`

**Anyone knows how long is this token valid?** I can not find this info on mentioned website.

I am also wondering, that this token is still valid, even when the user changes password. Shouldn't it generate a new one, or at least make the old on no more valid?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Answer to this question can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567586/token-authentication-for-restful-api-should-the-token-be-periodically-changed):

**SHORTLY: this token is valid infinitely long.**

If you would like to have token, which expires after certain time, please refere to examples shown in mentioned question.

Comment: Today I noticed that the default token was expired after some days. I did not do any customization. I wonder if there has been any change in Django.

Comment: @DavidPiao Please confirm, you said the token expired after some days without any customization? If so was a new one generated after it expired?

Comment: @Bruce, yes, I met such a case. But after that, could not reproduce it. I am not 100% sure.

Comment: It was my fault. Yes I confirm it lives forever

Comment: @DavidPiao A token expires (becomes invalid) if you log out on any client as there is only one token per user. Example: You log into you web application from 2 different computers with the same user. Both will use the same token. If you then log out on one computer, the token is removed (not expired). You will be logged out on the other computer as well.

Comment: By default, a token is not removed, meaning although you log out from one PC, the other PC still stays logged in.